# Scroll to end of ExpandableListView when clicking the last item

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

In the `OnGroupClickListener` of an `ExpandableListView`, I have:

```
expLista.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)   
    {
      // Pongo el valor de grupo clickeado correctamente
      grupoCLickeado = groupPosition;
      expLista.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
    }
}
```

This works fine except when clicking the last group. Once I click the last group, it scrolls until the group view, but not to down all.

Is it possible to scroll down more, to the end of the expandable list view?

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the following for this component  android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"

Comment: thanks for the hint, it works as expected, though it's not a smooth scroll ^^

Answer (score 2):

In General you don't need to scroll for first group in ExpadableListView. set transcriptMode other than first group in ExpadableListView.

```
getExpandableListView().setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int position) {

                if(position == 0) {
                    getExpandableListView().setTranscriptMode(ExpandableListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_DISABLED);
                }else{
                    getExpandableListView().setTranscriptMode(ExpandableListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
                }               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void scrollToEnd() {
    expLista.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            expLista.smoothScrollToPosition(getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}

private int getCount() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
            count++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: not working with me, maybe as my expandable in nestedScroll view?